# Simple button and link insertion Firefox addon: insertAdjacentHTML usage

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I would like to create a simple Firefox addon which inserts a link to Achavi (visualization tool) into OpenStreetMap changeset pages.

Example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/77264942 → https://overpass-api.de/achavi/?changeset=77264942

Here is my try:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "modify-page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/*"],
      "js": ["achavi-insert.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

achavi-insert.js:

```
    var address = new String(document.location);
    var a_strings = address.match(/changeset\/([0-9]+)/);
    //first capturing group
    var a_string = a_strings[1];

    var d1 = document.getElementById('browse-section');

    var zNode       = document.createElement('div');
    zNode.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="=window.open('
                    + '\'https://overpass-api.de/achavi/?changeset='+a_string+'\')">'
                    + 'Achavi</button>'
                    ;
    zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'achavi');

    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', zNode);
```

It is working when using `document.body.appendChild`, but I need to insert the button somewhere in the left sidebar.

How do I properly use `insertAdjacentHTML`?

Comment: There is a typo in your code, before `window.open` remove the unnecessary `=`.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

The second parameter is "The string to be parsed as HTML or XML and inserted into the tree." So don't pass a DOM node.

IMHO you have to use `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`, it depends on what you mean by "somewhere in the left sidebar"

Comment: Thanks, but the equivalent function for a DOM node insertAdjacentElement('afterend', zNode); also does not work.